# Vue Router incompatible with Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a problem with Vue Router with Laravel. It always says error 404 even though I already setup routes. I am struggling for several hours now. How can I provide solutions to this problem?

Here is my router,

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

// components
import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn.vue'
import SignUp from '../pages/SignUp.vue'
import Home from '../pages/Home.vue'

const routes = [
    { path: '/accounts/signin', component: SignIn},
    { path: '/accounts/signup', component: SignUp},
    { path: '/', component: Home},
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

and the web routes in Laralvel,

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::prefix('accounts')->group(function(){
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::get('/accounts/{any}',[AuthController::class, 'index'])->where('any','.*');
});
```

It prevents for adding `/route-name` prefix here. If I add, it will return an error.

Thanks! Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It says Error 404 Not Found. I tried to use ```php artisan route:list``` and my routes are not  updated there so I cleared it and it now works. Do I have to rerun the app again and again to apply changes?

Comment: can you explain more what do you want to do ?

Comment: I have a problem in routing. Browsing through the links I have created in my ```router```.  In every link I go, it says Error 404. So I tried to use ```php artisan route:clear``` to reset the routes and the links are now working again. I am really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Whenever you update something in code that is affected, you should clear config/view/route cache. You can do it in one command usually `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: Thank you so much  @Tpojka ! That will be noted.